# Jupyter Notebook and VirtualBox VM sharing the same port (conflict) - how do I change the VM port?

Tags: virtualbox, portforwarding

I had previously set up Jupyter Notebook on my Mac - recently I have set up a VirtualBox VM in my Mac and I realized I could not run my Jupyter Notebook when my VM is up and running (and vice versa).

Jupyter notebook is invoked by typing "Jupyter Notebook" in my Mac Terminal, and it shows that it is running on port 8888.   I understand VirtualBox default setting has the virtual machines running at port 8080 though.  How do I change the port for VirtualBox VM (from 8080 to something else) so I can use both VM and Jupyter Notebook at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I only know how to configure Jupyter Notebook, not VirtualBox because I don't
use it.

The simplest way to change the Jupyter port is defining an environment variable:

```py
# Default port is 8888. It will automatically try the next 50 ports
# (8889, 8890, ...) if it finds something is already using that port
export JUPYTER_PORT=8888
```

Put it in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`, depending on what shell you use.

---

More complicated is to generate and customize Jupyter's config:

```sh
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

It will tell you where the current config is dumped to. Then you can set
the port to whatever you want in that file:

```sh
## The port the notebook server will listen on (env: JUPYTER_PORT).
#  Default: 8888
# c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```